# pip install lxml and gdal failing in anaconda env

Tags: python, lxml, pip, gdal, anaconda

I've had persistent problems trying to install frameworks and packages requiring GDAL or lxml using pip within an anaconda env. I'm running OSX 10.8 with the Anaconda-installed Python 2.7.5.  I've got Xcode 4.6.3 with command line tools installed.

On packages requiring lxml or GDAL (just about every GIS package) I get clang errors. These are usually error 1 or error 254. I have the GDAL framework installed and (apparently) functioning with QGIS (though this refers to the system python and not the Anaconda distribution). I have the Anaconda- provided lxml, which seems to be working for scripting purposes within the env. I have tried updating lxml, to no effect. Two sample logs are included at the end of this question. Apologies that the question is a bit long...

The commonly repeated advice seems to be to get Xcode and CLT. As I said, I've already done that.

The other idea I've seen on the web has to do with the C compiler used to build the Anaconda Python distribution for OSX. I know absolutely nothing about C compilers, but I do know that pip installs packages to the system python without issue. When I start the system Python I get:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

for the Anaconda Python, I get:

```
Python 2.7.5 |Anaconda 1.6.1 (x86_64)| (default, Jun 28 2013, 22:20:13) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

note the difference in the GCC version. Is this significant?

Most recently pip failed trying to install kartograph.py. After running `pip install -r https://raw.github.com/kartograph/kartograph.py/master/requirements.txt` from within my env I get into trouble pretty quickly with

```
  Running setup.py egg_info for package lxml
    /Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.2.3.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/lib

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.py'
    warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'src/lxml/tests'
Downloading/unpacking ordereddict (from -r https://raw.github.com/kartograph/kartograph.py/master/requirements.txt (line 8))
  Downloading ordereddict-1.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package ordereddict

Downloading/unpacking tinycss (from -r https://raw.github.com/kartograph/kartograph.py/master/requirements.txt (line 9))
  Downloading tinycss-0.3.tar.gz (72kB): 72kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package tinycss
    Building with Cython 0.19.1.

    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
Downloading/unpacking argparse (from -r https://raw.github.com/kartograph/kartograph.py/master/requirements.txt (line 10))
  Downloading argparse-1.2.1.tar.gz (69kB): 69kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package argparse

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.orig' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.rej' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env24'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env25'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env26'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env27'
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): distribute in ./anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pykml->-r https://raw.github.com/kartograph/kartograph.py/master/requirements.txt (line 5))
Installing collected packages: GDAL, lxml, ordereddict, tinycss, argparse
  Running setup.py install for GDAL
    building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I/Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/include/python2.7 -I/Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/include -c extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/extensions/gdal_wrap.o
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:2230:11: warning: explicitly assigning a variable of type 'int' to itself [-Wself-assign]
                        res = SWIG_AddCast(res);
                        ~~~ ^              ~~~
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:2233:11: warning: explicitly assigning a variable of type 'int' to itself [-Wself-assign]
                        res = SWIG_AddCast(res);
                        ~~~ ^              ~~~
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:2853:10: fatal error: 'cpl_port.h' file not found
    #include "cpl_port.h"
             ^
    2 warnings and 1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/private/var/folders/l2/zvz4t5rs7pb3n1bc4_bdz6n4cbzgwl/T/pip-build-mmoncrief/GDAL/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/l2/zvz4t5rs7pb3n1bc4_bdz6n4cbzgwl/T/pip-JGdZ16-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7

copying gdal.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7

copying ogr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7

copying osr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7

copying gdalconst.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7

copying gdalnumeric.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/osgeo

copying osgeo/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/osgeo

copying osgeo/gdal.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/osgeo

copying osgeo/gdal_array.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/osgeo

copying osgeo/gdalconst.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/osgeo

copying osgeo/gdalnumeric.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/osgeo

copying osgeo/ogr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/osgeo

copying osgeo/osr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/osgeo

running build_ext

building 'osgeo._gdal' extension

creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/extensions

/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I/Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/include/python2.7 -I/Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/include -c extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/extensions/gdal_wrap.o

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:2230:11: warning: explicitly assigning a variable of type 'int' to itself [-Wself-assign]

                    res = SWIG_AddCast(res);

                    ~~~ ^              ~~~

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:2233:11: warning: explicitly assigning a variable of type 'int' to itself [-Wself-assign]

                    res = SWIG_AddCast(res);

                    ~~~ ^              ~~~

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:2853:10: fatal error: 'cpl_port.h' file not found

#include "cpl_port.h"

         ^

2 warnings and 1 error generated.

error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/private/var/folders/l2/zvz4t5rs7pb3n1bc4_bdz6n4cbzgwl/T/pip-build-mmoncrief/GDAL/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/l2/zvz4t5rs7pb3n1bc4_bdz6n4cbzgwl/T/pip-JGdZ16-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/l2/zvz4t5rs7pb3n1bc4_bdz6n4cbzgwl/T/pip-build-mmoncrief/GDAL
Storing complete log in /Users/mmoncrief/.pip/pip.log
```

I have also had clang errors related to lxml.etree. You'll see some of that peppered in the code above. Also, if I try simply `pip install lxml`:

```
Downloading/unpacking lxml
  Running setup.py egg_info for package lxml
    /Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.2.3.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/lib

    warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'src/lxml/tests'
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml
    /Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.2.3.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/lib
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/include -I/Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/include/libxml2 -I/private/var/folders/l2/zvz4t5rs7pb3n1bc4_bdz6n4cbzgwl/T/pip-build-mmoncrief/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -flat_namespace
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-flat_namespace'
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136455:17: warning: enumeration value '__pyx_e_4lxml_5etree_PARSER_DATA_INVALID' not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
            switch (__pyx_v_doc_ref->_type) {
                    ^
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140541:72: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *' to parameter of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        __pyx_t_1 = ((PyObject *)__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy(((struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *)__pyx_v_self->_context))); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[2]; __pyx_lineno = 543; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L9;}
                                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:138476:138: note: passing argument to parameter '__pyx_v_self' here
    static struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy(struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext *__pyx_v_self) {
                                                                                                                                             ^
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:141947:70: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *' to parameter of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
      __pyx_t_1 = ((PyObject *)__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy(((struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *)__pyx_v_stylesheet->_context))); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[2]; __pyx_lineno = 680; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:138476:138: note: passing argument to parameter '__pyx_v_self' here
    static struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy(struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext *__pyx_v_self) {
                                                                                                                                             ^
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:160878:19: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        PyObject_INIT(o, t);
                      ^
    /Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/include/python2.7/objimpl.h:164:69: note: expanded from macro 'PyObject_INIT'
        ( Py_TYPE(op) = (typeobj), _Py_NewReference((PyObject *)(op)), (op) )
                                                                        ^
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:162691:19: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        PyObject_INIT(o, t);
                      ^
    /Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/include/python2.7/objimpl.h:164:69: note: expanded from macro 'PyObject_INIT'
        ( Py_TYPE(op) = (typeobj), _Py_NewReference((PyObject *)(op)), (op) )
                                                                        ^
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:168247:19: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        PyObject_INIT(o, t);
                      ^
    /Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/include/python2.7/objimpl.h:164:69: note: expanded from macro 'PyObject_INIT'
        ( Py_TYPE(op) = (typeobj), _Py_NewReference((PyObject *)(op)), (op) )
                                                                        ^
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:170913:19: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        PyObject_INIT(o, t);
                      ^
    /Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/include/python2.7/objimpl.h:164:69: note: expanded from macro 'PyObject_INIT'
        ( Py_TYPE(op) = (typeobj), _Py_NewReference((PyObject *)(op)), (op) )
                                                                        ^
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:12774:13: warning: function '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_displayNode' is not needed and will not be emitted [-Wunneeded-internal-declaration]
    static void __pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_displayNode(xmlNode *__pyx_v_c_node, PyObject *__pyx_v_indent) {
                ^
    8 warnings generated.
    /usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/lib -arch x86_64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -L/Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/lib -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -o build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/etree.so
    clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
    clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 254
    Complete output from command /Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/private/var/folders/l2/zvz4t5rs7pb3n1bc4_bdz6n4cbzgwl/T/pip-build-mmoncrief/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/l2/zvz4t5rs7pb3n1bc4_bdz6n4cbzgwl/T/pip-gtlqX_-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
    /Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'

  warnings.warn(msg)

Building lxml version 3.2.3.

Building without Cython.

Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28

Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/lib

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml

creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron

copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources

creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng

creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

running build_ext

building 'lxml.etree' extension

creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/src

creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml

/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/include -I/Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/include/libxml2 -I/private/var/folders/l2/zvz4t5rs7pb3n1bc4_bdz6n4cbzgwl/T/pip-build-mmoncrief/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -flat_namespace

clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-flat_namespace'

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136455:17: warning: enumeration value '__pyx_e_4lxml_5etree_PARSER_DATA_INVALID' not handled in switch [-Wswitch]

        switch (__pyx_v_doc_ref->_type) {

                ^

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140541:72: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *' to parameter of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

    __pyx_t_1 = ((PyObject *)__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy(((struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *)__pyx_v_self->_context))); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[2]; __pyx_lineno = 543; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L9;}

                                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:138476:138: note: passing argument to parameter '__pyx_v_self' here

static struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy(struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext *__pyx_v_self) {

                                                                                                                                         ^

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:141947:70: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *' to parameter of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

  __pyx_t_1 = ((PyObject *)__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy(((struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *)__pyx_v_stylesheet->_context))); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[2]; __pyx_lineno = 680; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}

                                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:138476:138: note: passing argument to parameter '__pyx_v_self' here

static struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy(struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext *__pyx_v_self) {

                                                                                                                                         ^

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:160878:19: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]

    PyObject_INIT(o, t);

                  ^

/Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/include/python2.7/objimpl.h:164:69: note: expanded from macro 'PyObject_INIT'

    ( Py_TYPE(op) = (typeobj), _Py_NewReference((PyObject *)(op)), (op) )

                                                                    ^

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:162691:19: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]

    PyObject_INIT(o, t);

                  ^

/Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/include/python2.7/objimpl.h:164:69: note: expanded from macro 'PyObject_INIT'

    ( Py_TYPE(op) = (typeobj), _Py_NewReference((PyObject *)(op)), (op) )

                                                                    ^

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:168247:19: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]

    PyObject_INIT(o, t);

                  ^

/Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/include/python2.7/objimpl.h:164:69: note: expanded from macro 'PyObject_INIT'

    ( Py_TYPE(op) = (typeobj), _Py_NewReference((PyObject *)(op)), (op) )

                                                                    ^

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:170913:19: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]

    PyObject_INIT(o, t);

                  ^

/Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/include/python2.7/objimpl.h:164:69: note: expanded from macro 'PyObject_INIT'

    ( Py_TYPE(op) = (typeobj), _Py_NewReference((PyObject *)(op)), (op) )

                                                                    ^

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:12774:13: warning: function '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_displayNode' is not needed and will not be emitted [-Wunneeded-internal-declaration]

static void __pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_displayNode(xmlNode *__pyx_v_c_node, PyObject *__pyx_v_indent) {

            ^

8 warnings generated.

/usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/lib -arch x86_64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -L/Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/lib -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -o build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lxml/etree.so

clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11

clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)

error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 254

----------------------------------------
Command /Users/mmoncrief/anaconda/envs/py27/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/private/var/folders/l2/zvz4t5rs7pb3n1bc4_bdz6n4cbzgwl/T/pip-build-mmoncrief/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/l2/zvz4t5rs7pb3n1bc4_bdz6n4cbzgwl/T/pip-gtlqX_-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/l2/zvz4t5rs7pb3n1bc4_bdz6n4cbzgwl/T/pip-build-mmoncrief/lxml
Storing complete log in /Users/mmoncrief/.pip/pip.log
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. I've been working in Anaconda for other applications and would like to stay with this distribution.

Comment: I'm not clear on what exactly doesn't work with the Anaconda lxml.

Comment: The lxml log at the bottom is an example. I've had this failure on a couple of packages, I only include the attempt to download lxml directly as an exammple of what I'm seeing on other packages. Again, I have imported and use lxml for scripting purposes, but packages installs requiring lxml seem to fail regularly at lxml.etree, as above.

Comment: The log at the bottom is from pip install lxml. What doesn't work when you conda install lxml?

Comment: That seems to work ok, thanks. It's just updated me to lxml 3.2.3, and it's done so without any problems.  If I run into any other problems around lxml I'll post them.Any thoughts on the GDAL issue?

Comment: Compiling `lxml` usually takes a lot of memory - so if memory is your constraint, you should look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my $0.02, in my experience lxml installs on OS X have always caused problems because of the libmxl2 and libxslt dependencies. The specific issue here is that the 'cpl_port.h' is not being found suggesting that you don't have the headers for gdal on your system, a similar issue to the one I've encountered with lxml. I found this StackExchange post [gdal package missing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28966/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip) which addresses building and installing gdal with your specific error using pip and a virtual Ubuntu machine, but the idea is the same. The pip tool need to be told explicitly where to find the headers for gdal.

In general the issue is that OS X puts headers in non standard places for a *nix system, and quite often dependencies are several revision behind the version used for development of the packages you are trying to install. You can use MacPorts or something similar which will piggyback on OS X creating a structure similar to linux for all your dependencies with more current versions of libraries, but with virtualization getting so good and very few production systems running OS X I feel there is a far simpler solution. I am a 15+ year Apple user but when it comes to Python development on Mac my suggestion is use some kind of virtualization tool, I really like Vagrant with VirtualBox. Unless you are going to put your Python code into production on OS X or OS X Server it is better to develop on the final production OS so that you know during development what dependency versions are available and environment specific effects are present. Plus almost any other OS is easier to install packages like lxml and gdal on than OS X, with a simple "sudo apt-get install -y  --fix-missing" on Debian variants you can get the missing dependency and just move along. Vagrant will even sync your source files from the host to the guest so you can use your rich client IDE without much fuss.

Answer (score 0):

Use conda install gdal in the terminal, this will extract and install the gdal library